# mysql like query with special character '

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-like

I wrote query for filter data using name and wrote following query

```
SELECT * FROM (`abc`) WHERE (name LIKE "%test\'!&@#$\%-(3)\_er%")
```

It should return records which has name start with text "**test**"
but it will not instead of if I modify query like

```
SELECT * FROM (`abc`) WHERE (name LIKE "%test%\'!&@#$\%-(3)\_er%")
```

then it will give result. Why it is not give result with first query?
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: In your first query `%test` should be changed to `test%`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%` is the wildcard in the query.
So `%test` means everything that ends with `test`.
and `test%` means everything that begins with `test`.
and `%test%` means everything with `test` in it.

Simpy change your query to

`SELECT * FROM (`abc`) WHERE (name LIKE "test%")`

Comment: it is not work this SELECT `client_id` FROM (`client`) WHERE (client_name LIKE "%Client@$#%\'!&@#$\%-(3)\_er%")

Comment: @priyanka patel SELECT client_id FROM (client) WHERE (client_name LIKE "_____%@$#%\'!&@#$\%-(3)_er%")

Answer (score 0):

If you want records that start with `test`, simply use

```
SELECT * FROM (`abc`) WHERE (name LIKE "test%")
```

Comment: but if user enter any special character in search string then also it should work.

Comment: It will not return unless that exists if its part of the search query. then you have to filter out the special characters.